# Get the names of the customer with the most expensive Orders

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I've a small database with 4 tables: Customer - Order - OrderLine - Product, I'm playing around a bit with queries and am trying to fetch the names of the people with the most expensive order.

After some playing around I've come up with the following query, which shows the prices of all orders:

```
SELECT SUM(OrderLine.Amount * Product.Price) AS OrderLinePrice, Orders.Id, Customer.Lastname
FROM OrderLine, Product, Orders, Customer
WHERE OrderLine.ProductId = Product.Id
AND Orders.Id = OrderLine.OrderId
AND Customer.Id = Orders.CustomerId
GROUP BY Orders.Id, Customer.Lastname
ORDER BY OrderLinePrice DESC
```

Now what I conceptually need to do, or think I need to do, is apply a MAX() to select only the highest OrderLinePrice, but I'm  not succeeding with SQL Server complaining about not being able to perform aggregate functions on an expression that contains an aggregate...

=============== Update:

Currently my query looks like this:

```
SELECT t.CustomerLastName
FROM (
    SELECT SUM(OrderLine.Amount * Product.Price) AS OrderLinePrice, Orders.Id, Customer.Lastname AS CustomerLastName
    FROM OrderLine, Product, Orders, Customer
    WHERE OrderLine.ProductId = Product.Id
    AND Orders.Id = OrderLine.OrderId
    AND Customer.Id = Orders.CustomerId
    GROUP BY Orders.Id, Customer.Lastname
    ) AS t
WHERE t.OrderLinePrice = 
(
    SELECT MAX(s.OrderLinePrice) AS MaxOrderPrice
    FROM (
        SELECT SUM(OrderLine.Amount * Product.Price) AS OrderLinePrice, Orders.Id, Customer.Lastname AS CustomerLastName
        FROM OrderLine, Product, Orders, Customer
        WHERE OrderLine.ProductId = Product.Id
        AND Orders.Id = OrderLine.OrderId
        AND Customer.Id = Orders.CustomerId
        GROUP BY Orders.Id, Customer.Lastname
        ) AS s
)
ORDER BY CustomerLastName
```

This retrieves a list of customers from which the price of their order is equal to the price of the most expensive order. This retrieves exactly what I want, but it feels horribly redundant.

How should I start making this more efficient (if possible)?

Comment: What version of sql-server are you using?

Comment: It's been a while since I've done SQL, but how about "SELECT TOP 1 SUM(OrderLine.Amt...)?  That assumes you just want only *one* result...

Comment: I'm looking for the list of customers with an order as expensive as the most expensive order (see edit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, have you considered using explicit joins? It might just be a matter of taste, but perhaps you'll find queries with explicit joins clearer than those with implicit ones (or "comma" joins), like in your example.

As for the question, you could use `TOP (1) WITH TIES`, like this:

```
WITH ranked AS (
  SELECT
    SUM(ol.Amount * p.Price) AS OrderLinePrice,
    o.Id,
    c.Lastname AS CustomerLastName
  FROM OrderLine ol
    INNER JOIN Product  p ON p.Id = ol.ProductId
    INNER JOIN Orders   o ON o.Id = ol.OrderId
    INNER JOIN Customer c ON c.Id = o.CustomerId
  GROUP BY Orders.Id, Customer.Lastname
)
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES CustomerLastName
  FROM ranked
  ORDER BY OrderLinePrice DESC
) s
ORDER BY CustomerLastName
```

Or you could use `RANK()` or `DENSE_RANK()`, like this:

```
WITH ranked AS (
  SELECT
    SUM(ol.Amount * p.Price) AS OrderLinePrice,
    o.Id,
    c.Lastname AS CustomerLastName,
    RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(ol.Amount * p.Price) DESC) AS rnk
  FROM OrderLine ol
    INNER JOIN Product  p ON p.Id = ol.ProductId
    INNER JOIN Orders   o ON o.Id = ol.OrderId
    INNER JOIN Customer c ON c.Id = o.CustomerId
  GROUP BY Orders.Id, Customer.Lastname
)
SELECT CustomerLastName
FROM ranked
WHERE rnk = 1
ORDER BY CustomerLastName
```

If you are only interested in the topmost total price, `RANK()` is enough, but if you ever want customers for top *`n`* totals, use `DENSE_RANK()` instead and change the condition from `rnk = 1` to `rnk <= n`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in a couple of ways. Here is some suggestions:

**CTE**

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT SUM(OrderLine.Amount * Product.Price) AS OrderLinePrice, 
    Orders.Id, Customer.Lastname
    FROM OrderLine, Product, Orders, Customer
    WHERE OrderLine.ProductId = Product.Id
    AND Orders.Id = OrderLine.OrderId
    AND Customer.Id = Orders.CustomerId
    GROUP BY Orders.Id, Customer.Lastname
)
SELECT
    MAX(OrderLinePrice) AS MaxorderPrice
FROM
    CTE
```

**Subquery with max**

```
SELECT
    MAX(t.OrderLinePrice) AS MaxorderPrice
FROM
    (
        SELECT SUM(OrderLine.Amount * Product.Price) AS OrderLinePrice, 
            Orders.Id, Customer.Lastname
        FROM OrderLine, Product, Orders, Customer
        WHERE OrderLine.ProductId = Product.Id
        AND Orders.Id = OrderLine.OrderId
        AND Customer.Id = Orders.CustomerId
        GROUP BY Orders.Id, Customer.Lastname
    ) AS t
```

**Top 1 with order by**

```
SELECT TOP 1
    t.Amount
FROM
    (
        SELECT SUM(OrderLine.Amount * Product.Price) AS OrderLinePrice, 
            Orders.Id, Customer.Lastname
        FROM OrderLine, Product, Orders, Customer
        WHERE OrderLine.ProductId = Product.Id
        AND Orders.Id = OrderLine.OrderId
        AND Customer.Id = Orders.CustomerId
        GROUP BY Orders.Id, Customer.Lastname
    ) AS t
ORDER BY t.OrderLinePrice DESC
```

**EDIT**

Maybe something like this:

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT SUM(OrderLine.Amount * Product.Price) AS OrderLinePrice, 
    Orders.Id, Customer.Lastname
    FROM OrderLine, Product, Orders, Customer
    WHERE OrderLine.ProductId = Product.Id
    AND Orders.Id = OrderLine.OrderId
    AND Customer.Id = Orders.CustomerId
    GROUP BY Orders.Id, Customer.Lastname
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    CTE
WHERE 
    CTE.OrderLinePrice=(SELECT MAX(CTE2.OrderLinePrice) FROM CTE AS CTE2)
```

Or if you want the max by customer lastname. You can do it like this:

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT SUM(OrderLine.Amount * Product.Price) AS OrderLinePrice, 
    Orders.Id, Customer.Lastname
    FROM OrderLine, Product, Orders, Customer
    WHERE OrderLine.ProductId = Product.Id
    AND Orders.Id = OrderLine.OrderId
    AND Customer.Id = Orders.CustomerId
    GROUP BY Orders.Id, Customer.Lastname
)
SELECT
    MAX(OrderLinePrice) AS MaxPrice,
    Lastname
FROM
    CTE
GROUP BY 
    CTE.Lastname
```

Comment: Almost :) I need the list of names of peoples with the most expensive order. So basically I need this to get the price of the most expensive order and then issue that value as a delimiter to the same query.. Sounds inefficient :)

Comment: So which customer do you need. If you just order OrderLinePrice like you do now. You will get that list you are taking about. Or how do you except to limit them more?

Comment: I'm looking for the list of customers with an order price equal to the max price.

Comment: Which then looks like: SELECT t.CustomerLastName
FROM (
 SELECT SUM(OrderLine.Amount * Product.Price) AS OrderLinePrice, Orders.Id, Customer.Lastname AS CustomerLastName
 FROM OrderLine, Product, Orders, Customer
 WHERE OrderLine.ProductId = Product.Id
 AND Orders.Id = OrderLine.OrderId
 AND Customer.Id = Orders.CustomerId
 GROUP BY Orders.Id, Customer.Lastname
 ) AS t
WHERE t.OrderLinePrice = 
(
 // query to get the price of the most expensive order
)

But this seems quite redundant somehow :)

Comment: Updated the answer. Have a look